# Why is $\displaystyle \cos^{-1} \left( \sin 2\theta \right) = \frac{\pi}{2} - 2\theta$?

Tags: trigonometry

In the end of an exercise I reach the point that I state that the answer is $\cos^{-1} \left( \sin 2\theta \right)$. The book gives, as an answer, $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2} - 2\theta$.

By plotting in Wolfram I coud see that, for in interval considered ($0 < \theta < \frac{\pi}{4}$) they are equivalent. But whay is that? How can I show that?

Comment: $\cos^{-1}\phi+\sin^{-1}\phi=\pi/2$

Comment: These types of problems usually has a corresponding interval where $\theta $ lies. For example, the equality is not true for $\theta=5\pi/4$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\displaystyle \cos^{-1} \left( \sin 2\theta \right) = \frac{\pi}{2} - 2\theta$$

Take cosine of both sides to get the equivalent statement for $0 < \theta < \frac{\pi}{4}$

$$ \sin 2\theta  = \cos(\frac{\pi}{2} - 2\theta)
$$

Which is true for every $\theta$

Comment: You assumed what needs to be proved.

Comment: The same method can be used to prove that $x=-x$, for all $x$ (take square).

Comment: @chhro I edited my answer.

Comment: And it's still wrong. The statements are certainly not equivalent. One is true for all $\theta$, the other is not. If you apply a **non-injective** function $f$ to $A$ and $B$, to find that $f(A)=f(B)$, you **can't** conclude that $A=B$.

Comment: Unless the OP add an interval for $\theta$, there is no satisfactory answer to this.

Answer (score 2):

If $0 \le \phi \le \frac \pi 2$ then

$\cos^{-1} \cos \phi = \phi$

If $0 \le \phi \le \frac \pi 2$ then $0 \le \frac \pi 2 - \phi \le \frac \pi 2$ and $\sin \phi = \cos (\frac \pi 2 - \phi)$

and $\cos^{-1}(\sin \phi) =$

$\cos^{-1}(\cos \frac \pi 2 - \phi) =$

$\frac \pi 2 - \phi$.

And if $0\le \theta \le \frac \pi 4$ and $\phi = 2\theta$ then $0\le \phi \le \frac \pi 2$ and

$\cos^{-1}(\sin 2\theta) = $

$\cos^{-1}(\sin \phi) =$

$\cos^{-1}(\cos \frac \pi 2 - \phi) =$

$\frac \pi 2 - \phi$

$\frac \pi 2 - 2\theta$.

Comment: +1 At long last a satisfying answer, that does not try to hide injectivity under the carpet :)

Answer (score 1):

It is based on the trigonometric identity: $\sin(x)=\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)$,  assume $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$
$\sin2\theta=\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-2\theta)$

Take the inverse function of cosine from both side

$\cos^{-1}\sin(2\theta)=\cos^{-1}\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-2\theta)$

$\cos^{-1}(\sin2\theta)=\frac{\pi}{2}-2\theta$  ,  as $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: It could be noticed that $\cos^{-1}\cos x=x$ only of $x\in[0,\pi]$.

Comment: @ Jean-Claude Arbaut Yes, it is.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
\sin \rho &= \sin \rho \\
&=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\rho\right) && \text{the sine-cosine complementary relation}\\ 
\cos^{-1}(\sin \rho)&=\frac{\pi}{2}-\rho && \text{taking inverse cosine of both sides} \\
\cos^{-1}(\sin 2\theta)&=\frac{\pi}{2}-2\theta && \text{substitute} \qquad \rho = 2 \theta
\end{align}$$